# Google Charts JSON problems

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access JSON from the Flurry API to graph information that is there. However, when I am trying to run the graph, I get the `Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string` alert in the space where I am sending the array. The following is my code:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(fillData);

function fillData() { 
  var dataArray = [];
  var tempArray = ['@name', '@totalCount'];

  dataArray.push(tempArray);
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open('GET', '//flurry address', true);
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
    if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        for (i = 0;i < obj.parameters.key[0].value[i]["@name"]; i++)
        {
          dataArray.push([obj.parameters.key[0].value[i]["@name"], obj.parameters.key[0].value[i]["@totalCount"]]);
          alert(dataArray[i]);
        }
     }
  }
};
  //xmlhttp.send(null);

drawBasic(dataArray);

}


function drawBasic(dataarray) {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataarray);

  var options = {
    title: 'Login Counts',
    chartArea: {width: '50%'},
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Login Count',
      minValue: 0
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Company'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: where is the json? did you try to load few rows? like 2 or 3. You are calling `drawBasic(dataArray);` outside onreadystatechange . Did you try to call it after the alert? inside `onreadystatechange `

Comment: "parameters":{"key":[{"@name":"app","value":      [{"@totalCount":"3","@name":"SLK_demo"},{"@totalCount":"6","@name":"GOLD"},{"@totalCount":"72","@name":"app_Demo"},{"@totalCount":"9","@name":"mortgage360"},{"@totalCount":"378","@name":"lenderx"},{"@totalCount":"2","@name":"southeast"}]},{"@name":"button","value":{"@totalCount":"470","@name":"Login"}}]}}

Comment: That is the json that I am using from flurry.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code that is shown here:

https://jsfiddle.net/9j5x97r7/2/

**The jsfiddle Is not working because i couldnt load the API and i dont have time. But if you make it load it works (try in your code).**

The first row is different as you made. The `for` is wrong

And you need to parse the number because in the response is a string.

Let me know if it helps you